# Getting error eg. unexpected keyword or identifier in htaccess file, how to remove it or is there any other way to remove file extension from url

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, syntax-error, htmlextensions

My .htaccess file code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: If that's all you have in your `.htaccess` file then it would seen mod_rewrite is not enabled on your server, otherwise, there's nothing syntactically wrong with the directives as posted.

Comment: thanks for this information, but can u tell how can I check whether mod_rewrite is enabled in live server extension of vscode, as I am not using xampp or wamp